# get website information by URL in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, html-head

With reference to the stack overflow question:

> [Get website information with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163660/get-website-information-with-jquery)

I want to accomplish a similar task in Node.js to get the information of the website like: Image and Name when I provide the url.

I am aware about the HEAD Request in Node but it does not pull that information, rather it returns HTML Headers.

How can I do so?

A sample example can be when we send a url in Slack as a message it pull the Image and meta and displays automatically.

With a small research I ended up making a request like this:

```
var request = require('request');
request("http://stackoverflow.com", {method: 'HEAD'}, function (err, r es, body){
console.log(res.headers);
});
```

and got basic header info:

```
{"cache-control":"private","content-length":"245925","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-request-guid":"02d28d15-13e3-4d2e-8495-fa0ff5922224","accept-ranges":"bytes","date":"Mon, 06 Mar 2017 14:44:52 GMT","via":"1.1 varnish","connection":"close","x-served-by":"cache-lcy1130-LCY","x-cache":"MISS","x-cache-hits":"0","x-timer":"S1488811492.680621,VS0,VE89","x-dns-prefetch-control":"off","set-cookie":["prov=fbdc85f1-c72a-bcc4-8538-2572d0580c74; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly"]}
```

But it does not have image and Name information which I am precisely requiring.

Comment: Are you looking for a module to fetch, parse, and summarize a URL?  Or are you asking how to use `http.request()`?  Without giving more information about what you've done so far and how you're trying to approach this, it's very difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: updated with code.
I am open to the module approach, i tried the request approach but maybe I am missing something

Comment: Well, the clue to why it only returned headers is in the method name.  What you will need to do is fetch the entire page using a GET request, parse the response body, and extract the bits you want.

Comment: and do we have any node module to support that??